# How to tell jQuery that all selectors I write should be limited to the object being worked on?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made this incredible plugin that will change the fate of the world http://jsfiddle.net/4phfC/1/:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>    

$.fn.colorText = function(color) {

    $('.bar', $(this)).css('color', color);

    // a million other lines of code here...

}

$(function() {

    $("#div1").colorText("red");

});

</script>

<div id="div1" class="foo" style="width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid green">
    <span class="bar">Hello</span>
</div>

<div id="div2" class="foo" style="width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid green">
    <span class="bar">Good Bye</span>
</div>
```

In order to effect just the span tag with the class "bar" that is within the object that I attached the plugin to and not the other one on the page I did:

```
$('.bar', $(this)).whatever();
```

But notice the spot where the million other lines of code will go, it would be somehwat of a pain to use this convention throughout the rest of the plugin.

Is there any way to tell jQuery from now on all selectors I declare are applicable only to the element that the plugin is attached, so that I can use selectors like normal:

```
$('.bar').whatever();
```

and this won't affect any ".bar"'s that are outside of the element being worked on.

Comment: What's wrong with caching the results once (if you want, you can use `find`): `var bars = $(this).find('.bar');` and from then on you don't need  to use selectors, just refer to the variable. Or, keep chaing calls from `$(this).find('.bar').doSomething().end().doSomethingElse()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with all of the comments about caching selectors, but if you still really wanted to do something like you are describing, you could always encapsulate the functionality in another function.

```
$.fn.colorText = function(color) {
    var that = this;

    function selectInScope(selector) {
        return $(selector,that);
    }

    selectInScope('.bar').css('color', color);

    // a million other lines of code here...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, not that I know of, but you *could* do this:

```
$(this).find('.bar')
```

If you really wanted to, you could do something like this:

```
!function($) {
    function jqScoped(scope) {
        return function() {
            return $.apply(window, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).concat([scope]);
        };
    }
    var jqUnscoped=$;
    $.fn.colorText=function(color) {
        var jQuery=jqScoped(jqUnscoped(this)), $=jQuery;
        $('.bar').css('color', color);
    };
}(jQuery);
```

...but that might not work for non-selector arguments to `$` (although I haven't tested it).

Answer (score 0):

While there might not be a selector, you can save a jQuery object as a variable, and use it from then on in.  For example...

```
$.fn.colorText = function(color) {
   var thisBar = $('.bar', $(this));

   thisBar.css('color', color);

   // continue to use thisBar...
   // a million other lines of code here...
}
```